# Travis CI run scripts in parallel

Tags: bash, travis-ci

My Travis YML runs 3 scripts that are not dependent on each other.

I'd like to run them in parallel to increase speed.

Following this article: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/speeding-up-the-build/

I modified my `_travis.yml` as such:

```
language: ruby
cache: bundler
env:
  - BUILD=buildPDF.sh
  - BUILD=buildPages.sh
  - BUILD=buildHosting.sh
script: "./$BUILD"
```

When Travis runs I get the error `The command "./$BUILD" exited with 126.`

Things I've tried so far:

- `script: "./${BUILD}"`
- Remove the spaces in the list (`-BUILD=...`)

Comment: The standard meaning of 126: Command invoked cannot execute. http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html

Comment: Yes the question is why doesn't it convert the $BUILD variable

Comment: Same thing:
`$ ./${BUILD}
/home/travis/build.sh: line 41: ./: Is a directory
The command "./${BUILD}" exited with 126.`

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You need to put name of your scripts in quotes and then put $BUILD variable into curly braces as @набиячлэвэли suggested. Following worked for me:

```
env:
- TEST_SUITE="travis-job-codecov-linter.sh"
- TEST_SUITE="travis-job-cypress-boxes.sh"
- TEST_SUITE="travis-job-cypress-products.sh"
- TEST_SUITE="travis-job-cypress-signup.sh"
- TEST_SUITE="travis-job-cypress-controls.sh"
- TEST_SUITE="travis-job-build.sh"
script: ./${TEST_SUITE}
```