# Speeding up the Travis build

Tags: ruby-on-rails, travis-ci

I've read [official doc](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/speeding-up-the-build/), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34117441/travis-ci-run-scripts-in-parallel) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50110360/how-to-make-travisci-run-flow-test-lint-in-parallel/50117342#50117342) SO posts. Cited links explains how to run tests in parallel, but not how to build and test only part of them. What I am looking for is: how to set Travis CI for "partial" build. If my app has 5 parts, and developer commits code only in part 3, then I need just that part to be built and tested, while later during night there will be full build.

So, to rephrase, my question is how to setup "partial" build and "full" build as separate and execute them depending on committed code or cron job (for nightly build)?

Also I'd like to run separately front and back-end builds depending on commit. Unit and Integration testing should be also separated on partial and nightly build. App is Ruby on back and Angular on front.

Answer (score 1):

A good starting point for what you are trying to achieve would be to look into Travis CI's [conditional jobs](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/conditional-builds-stages-jobs/#conditional-jobs) feature.

For example, you would be able to define different commands to execute if the build is a cron build or a push/pr build e.g.

```
jobs:
  include:
    - name: partial
      script: ./partial_tests.sh
      if: type = push OR type = pull_request
    - name: full
      script: ./full_tests.sh
      if: type = cron
```

Take note that running different commands based on which files were modified in the commit isn't supported "natively" at this time but it could be implemented "manually" e.g. with `git diff`.

Hope this helps!